How do I resolve deleted Packagist package that was a dependency of a dependency?
Our PHP application has a Packagist dependency aaa/foo defined in our composer.json file.
This package has a dependency of a deleted Packagist package, let's call it: bbb/bar.
This is breaking our composer install.
I have a copy of the deleted package (bbb/bar) from an old install. What is the easiest way to resolve this given aaa/foo has not been updated?
I'm hoping there's a way I can copy the source of the missing package to a directory in a lib directory of the codebase and map it in composer.json... but I don't think aaa/foo would recognize that override.

If bbb/bar is dead, I'd hope that aaa/foo would recognize and deal with it in some way. If they don't, I think I'd probably fork aaa/foo. Then I'd either solve for bbb/bar, or re-upload bbb/bar as my own (at least temporarily) and rely on that.

@ChrisHaas There's no need to fork aaa/foo if all you're doing is replacing bbb/bar with a like-for-like fork. It may be that aaa/foo will be happy to change their dependency to myforkofbbb/bar, and until they do you can use "replace" to tell Composer it's substitutable.

@IMSoP, that's why I said I hoped that aaa/foo would deal with it. If they don't I'd fork, solve (embed, re-host, rewrite) and send a PR back up to aaa/foo. If they aren't interested in the PR then that project is probably dead, too, at least from my perspective. I do host some bbb/bar equivalent packages because of this exact reason, and I'm honestly not the expert on these, so I don't know if I want to be the perpetual maintainer on behalf of aaa/foo for the entire world.

@ChrisHaas My point is that if you are willing to host a copy of bbb/bar, you can do that as a first step, without also forking aaa/foo. That solves the immediate problem, while you work out whether aaa/foo is actively maintained, and what to do in the longer term.

@IMSoP, I think we're both on the same overall page in general, and I don't disagree with anything you are saying.

If you have the deleted bbb/bar package, place it in a local folder.
In the composer.json file of the downloaded and locally placed bbb/bar package, set the required version number:
{
    "name": "bbb/bar",
    "description": "...",
    "type": "library",
    "version": "1.2.3", // Here
}

Then, in the project where you are using aaa/foo, reference your local package so that it can be installed as a "dependency":
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./lib/bbb-bar"
    }
],
"require": {
    "aaa/foo": "^1.0",
    "bbb/bar": "1.2.3"
}


The manual for composer.json has a description of the "replace" section:

Map of packages that are replaced by this package. This allows you to fork a package, publish it under a different name with its own version numbers, while packages requiring the original package continue to work with your fork because it replaces the original package.

You can use this to replace a third-party package in two different ways:

You can create a fork of the package, with a new name, and list it as "replacing" the original. e.g. if the original was acme/frobulator, you might create coder1/frobulator and list "replace": {"acme/frobulator": "self.version"}.

You can either make your fork public on https://packagist.org as a service to other users who have the same problem, or use a private repository in your main application's composer.json.
Either way, you would then list "coder1/frobulator" in your normal "require" section, and Composer would know it meets the requirements of other packages which ask for "acme/frobulator" at the same version


If you're just using it in this one application, you could copy the code to somewhere in your own repository, and

mark the application itself as the replacement for a specific version, e.g. "replace": {"acme/frobulator": "1.42.0"}
tell composer where to autoload it, e.g. "psr-4": {"Acme\Frobulator": "third-party/acme/frobulator/src"}




Import Note: You should make an effort to check that you have the legal ability to use or host the missing package. It's possible that the licence it was distributed under limits how you can use or distribute your fork.
It's also possible that it was removed because it was in breach of somebody else's copyright or other rights; if so, the licence it was distributed under is invalid (put crudely: if they stole it, it was never up to them whether you could use it).

I would try the following:

put the code from bbb/bar into any local lib folder in your application
add the proper autoloader to your application's composer.json such that the code from the package is found when it needs to be imported
add bbb/bar to the replace section of your composer.json

It might be neccessary to call composer update bbb/bar once such that the package is removed from the lock file
